# FFT Implementation and using its Output

Tags: c, arduino, fft

Im currently working on a project where a PRO Trinket does a 64 point FFT of an Audio Input and sends the Output/Magnitude of the bins to arduino which controlls a RGB Matrix.

I derived my fft code from http://wiki.openmusiclabs.com/wiki/ArduinoFFT
I cant seem to figure out how to exactly use the output (fft_log_out) and send out the data although I think that my code is close to working. In Line 73 I get this ERROR: 'freq_array' was not declared in this scope
It would be great to get some help on this, I have been working on this for weeks :(

```
/*
fft_adc.pde
guest openmusiclabs.com 8.18.12
example sketch for testing the fft library.
it takes in data on ADC0 (Analog0) and processes them
with the fft. the data is sent out over the serial
port at 115.2kb.  there is a pure data patch for
visualizing the data.
*/

#define LOG_OUT 1 // use the log output function
#define FFT_N 64 // set to 64 point fft


#include <FFT.h> // include the library

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200); // use the serial port
TIMSK0 = 0; // turn off timer0 for lower jitter
ADCSRA = 0xe5; // set the adc to free running mode
ADMUX = 0x40; // use adc0
DIDR0 = 0x01; // turn off the digital input for adc0
int freq_array [32];
}

void loop() {
while(1) { // reduces jitter
cli();  // UDRE interrupt slows this way down on arduino1.0
for (int i = 0 ; i < 124 ; i += 2) { // save 64 samples
  while(!(ADCSRA & 0x10)); // wait for adc to be ready
  ADCSRA = 0xf5; // restart adc
  byte m = ADCL; // fetch adc data
  byte j = ADCH;
  int k = (j << 8) | m; // form into an int
  k -= 0x0200; // form into a signed int
  k <<= 6; // form into a 16b signed int
  fft_input[i] = k; // put real data into even bins
  fft_input[i+1] = 0; // set odd bins to 0
}
fft_window(); // window the data for better frequency response
fft_reorder(); // reorder the data before doing the fft
fft_run(); // process the data in the fft
fft_mag_log(); // take the output of the fft


// Amplitude Ranges  if else tree

for(int j=0; j<32; j++){    
if (fft_log_out[j] < 2000 && fft_log_out[j] > 180){freq_array[j] = 16;}
else{ if (fft_log_out[j] <= 180 && fft_log_out[j] > 160){freq_array[j] = 15;}
else{ if (fft_log_out[j] <= 160 && fft_log_out[j] > 130){freq_array[j] = 14;}
else{ if (fft_log_out[j] <= 130 && fft_log_out[j] > 110){freq_array[j] = 13;}
else{ if (fft_log_out[j] <= 110 && fft_log_out[j] > 90){freq_array[j] = 12;}
else{ if (fft_log_out[j] <= 90 && fft_log_out[j] > 70){freq_array[j] = 11;}
else{ if (fft_log_out[j] <= 70 && fft_log_out[j] > 60){freq_array[j] = 10;}
else{ if (fft_log_out[j] <= 60 && fft_log_out[j] > 50){freq_array[j] = 9;}
else{ if (fft_log_out[j] <= 50 && fft_log_out[j] > 40){freq_array[j] = 8;}
else{ if (fft_log_out[j] <= 40 && fft_log_out[j] > 30){freq_array[j] = 7;}
else{ if (fft_log_out[j] <= 30 && fft_log_out[j] > 20){freq_array[j] = 6;}
else{ if (fft_log_out[j] <= 20 && fft_log_out[j] > 15){freq_array[j] = 5;}
else{ if (fft_log_out[j] <= 15 && fft_log_out[j] > 11){freq_array[j] = 4;}
else{ if (fft_log_out[j] <= 11 && fft_log_out[j] > 8){freq_array[j] = 3;}
else{ if (fft_log_out[j] <= 8 && fft_log_out[j] > 5){freq_array[j] = 2;}
else{ if (fft_log_out[j] <= 5 && fft_log_out[j] > 2){freq_array[j] = 1;}
else{ if (fft_log_out[j] <= 2 && fft_log_out[j] > 0){freq_array[j] = 0;}
 }}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}

sei();


String sta = "M";
String aa = str(freq_array[0]); //ERROR: 'freq_array' was not declared in this scope
String bb = str(freq_array[1]);
String cc = str(freq_array[2]);
String dd = str(freq_array[3]);
String ee = str(freq_array[4]);
String ff = str(freq_array[5]);
String gg = str(freq_array[6]);
String hh = str(freq_array[7]);
String ii = str(freq_array[8]);
String jj = str(freq_array[9]);
String kk = str(freq_array[10]);
String ll = str(freq_array[11]);
String mm = str(freq_array[12]);
String nn = str(freq_array[13]);
String oo = str(freq_array[14]);
String pp = str(freq_array[15]);
String qq = str(freq_array[16]);
String rr = str(freq_array[17]);
String ss = str(freq_array[18]);
String tt = str(freq_array[19]);
String uu = str(freq_array[20]);
String vv = str(freq_array[21]);
String ww = str(freq_array[22]);
String xx = str(freq_array[23]);
String yy = str(freq_array[24]);
String zz = str(freq_array[25]);
String aaa = str(freq_array[26]);
String bbb = str(freq_array[27]);
String ccc = str(freq_array[28]);
String ddd = str(freq_array[28]);
String eee = str(freq_array[30]);
String fff = str(freq_array[31]);

String com = ",";
String newl = "\n";

String send1 = sta + aa + com + bb + com + cc + com + dd + com + ee + com + ff + com + gg + com + hh + com + ii + com + jj + com + kk + com + ll + com + mm + com + nn + com + oo + com + pp + com + qq + com + rr + com + ss + com + tt + com + uu + com + vv + com + ww + com + xx + com + yy + com + zz + com + aaa + com + bbb + com + ccc + com + ddd + com + eee + com + fff + newl;
Serial.write(send1);


}

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error

> ```
> ERROR: 'freq_array' was not declared in this scope
> ```

because `freq_array` was declared as a local variable in the `setup()` function scope, and is thus not accessible outside this scope where you are trying to use it.

To resolve this error you simply need to declare `freq_array` at the file scope by moving the declaration to be outside the `setup()` function body:

```
int freq_array[32];
void setup() { ...
```

Comment: Good Point. That fixed the error but now it says 'str' is not declared, maybe because im writing in C and not C++? I have never used str before. How would I implement this in C?

Comment: Indeed `str` is not C. You could try `char aa[BUF_SIZE]; sprintf(aa, "%.0f", freq_array[idx])` with appropriate buffer size for each variable (alternatively size the buffer for the whole string, 1024 is probably enough for the illustrated case).